# connection refused from server to local host

Tags: ssh, osx, r

I have an R script on a remote server. The script needs my local display in order to generate plots.

```
me@local$ ssh -Y me@remote_ip
me@remote$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:52.0

$ Rscript myscript.R
connect localhost port 6012: Connection refused
```

The script does the job, however I'd like to get rid of this connection error message. Ideally I'd like a solution to fix this. I read on some other threads that it would be my local computer that does not allow the connection from the remote server. I have no idea how to solve that as my mac `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall` shows the firewall is off. So how am I supposed to authorise the connection from the remote server back to my local computer? Unless the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Since you're running the command on the remote host, `localhost` in this case refers to the remote host, not the computer that you're connecting from.

Comment: Exactly. Following this idea, I generated the remote's `ssh keys` and put them in my local's ssh_authorized keys. Was it one right step to take? It does not solve the issue though